# Creating a dll to import MYSQL data

Tags: c#, mysql, dll

Hi I would like to know how to create a dll that is written in say, c# that gets data from the  columns of MYSQL database that is hosted online, so i am bit a confused as the data in MYSQL gets updated very often how to ensure that dll is pulling the information?

I am very new to creating dll never have it done before.

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have got your windows class libarary set up. You need to decide what data the dll needs to give your calling application/s. You then need to expose these methods in the dll so that you can call them when needed. You should use Interfaces for these methods

```
namespace ProductExampleInterfaces
{

    public interface IProductData
    {
        IList<Product> GetAllProducts();
        string GetProductName(int id);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The above interface would be used in your calling application as following

```
using MySqlExmpleDll;
...

class ProductService
{
    private IProductData _productData;

    public ProductService(IProductData productData)
    {
        _productData = productData;
    }

    public IList<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        IList<Product> products;
        products = _productData.GetAllProducts();
        ...
        return products;
    }

}
```

Now, if GetAllProducts() is returning data then you know you are on track.

Comment: ok i will do this and get back to u..but one question lets say i do this and how to test if the data is flowing?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a bit of (untested code). Did you want any changes to the MySql database to be monitored and then filtered down to your main app? If thats the case then you will have to have an application running on your server with maybe a MarshalByRefObject to push triggered events down to your calling app.

Comment: Hi astro no i dont need to have any changes made on mysql database, the input to the mysql database it self will be actually from SQL server which i am familiar with, so the data in the online MYSQL will be just storing what ever the incoming database is providing to it.. But i fail to notice any method that is getting the input from MYSQL server is this the part u meant to say that i have to have a separate application to pull and push the data to the dll?..tks

Comment: found this link for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.71).aspx in your case just create a method in the dll to connect to the mysql database and then take some input values (e.g. productname, productvalue) and insert/update the table using the connection.

Comment: hi astro,thanks for the link going thru now, r u by chance familiar with MQL4 language basically its a programming language for financial trading and i did some research before i dive in to the dll development wether is C or C# best for that programming language..pls advice as i read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921541/programming-language-for-creating-dll-c-or-c-sharp?rq=1     so C# only for .net usage?

Comment: If your main application is going to be written in C# then you should create your dll in C#. I dont know anything about MQL to give you advice on integrating dlls into your app. Maybe you should post another question detailing your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

To create the DLL when you create a new project in Visual Studio make sure you select an option that compiles to a DLL, such as a Windows Class Library.

To add an external DLL to your own project, you can right-click on References for your project in your Solution Explorer and select "Add Reference" then browse to the location of the DLL.  You'll then be able to use any functionality contained within that DLL.